# How to make a query that passes the deadline of the time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a table with name **Task** as shown below that have a property with name **stopTime**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task", schema = "public")
public class Task {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @NotEmpty
 private String date;

 @NotEmpty
 private String startTime;

 @NotEmpty
 private String stopTime;

 @NotEmpty
 @Column(length=1000)
 private String description;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="USER_EMAIL")
 private User user;

 public Long getId() {
    return id;
 }

 public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 public String getDate() {
    return date;
 }

 public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
 }

 public String getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
 }

 public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
 }

 public String getStopTime() {
    return stopTime;
 }

 public void setStopTime(String stopTime) {
    this.stopTime = stopTime;
 }

 public String getDescription() {
    return description;
 }

 public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
 }

 public User getUser() {
    return user;
 }

 public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
 }
```

Now I am making a query in **PostgreSQL** that **select** all the tasks that have passed the deadline as shown below:

```
@Query("select stopTime from Task where ")
List<String> deleteAll();
```

. It is recommended to compare the **stopTime** of task with **current time**. Please help me to complete this query.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a HQL/JPQL solution or a SQL solution? If you are looking for a SQL solution you should post the table definition as `create table` statements, not as Java code

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare column with type datetime use [INTERVAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)  AND [BETWEEN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html)

```
select * from Task where stopTime BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL '3 day') AND NOW()
```

for removing purpose try this `select * from Task where stopTime < NOW()` OR `select * from Task where stopTime IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @maximShubim why do I have to use INTERVAL '3 day' when I want to select all rows that have passed the deadline?

Comment: @FabioPlaka you can use any interval that you want. this just example

Comment: @MaximShubim how can I use the interval from creation?

Comment: @FabioPlaka 
I assume that you execute this query at some selected interval according to the schedule. so that the old records do not get again you need to be limited datetime of the previous query. or you can use additional flag to mark records are already processed also.

Comment: @FabioPlaka for removing purpose try this `select * from Task where stopTime < NOW()` OR `select * from Task where stopTime IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @MaximShubim it gives me error in 'NOW()'. I am making with Java code and instead if 'NOW()' maybe I should put 'current_time'.

Comment: @FabioPlaka Hibernate, for example, supports current_date() function instead postges NOW()

Comment: @FabioPlaka Yep, use current_time()